# Trigonometric integral of $f(x)=(x^2)(\sin(x^2))$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I've tried with the chain rule and $u$-subtitution ($u=\sqrt{x}$) but I get nothing. Can you help me please? $$\int (sqrt{x})(\sin(x)) \ dx$$

Comment: Is the new edit what you are asking? Or is it $\sin^2(x)$

Comment: This leads to not an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function)

Comment: Sorry I flagged wrongly. I misread it as $x^2 \sin^2 x$. And as Alexey Burdin suggested, this does not yield elementary function. Check out in wolframalpha.

Comment: Is the new edit what I'm asking. It's difficult.